# Why Elasicsearch query show partial results?

Tags: elasticsearch

i get partial result from search into Elasticsearch:

```
curl -XGET 'http://1.1.1.1:9200/my.index-*/api/_search?q=name:foo'
```

I get:

```
{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 204,
    "successful": 204,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 543,
    "max_score": 2.734601,
    "hits": [ .......
```

And show only 10 hits...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from and size, see the documentation on elastic website.

[click here to go to the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "name" : "foo" }
    }
}
```

it defaults to 0 and 10, the reason you're getting only 10 hits

Comment: Ops...Thanks! Works